# sequence defined by norm

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(u_n)_n$ be defined by: 
$\quad \begin{cases}u_1=1 & \\
\\
u_n=\left( \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}u_{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} & \end{cases} $

- Show that $u_{n}\to +\infty$ and $u_n  \simeq  u_{n+1}$.

Let $v_{n}:=u_{n+1}-u_{n}$.

- Show that $(v_{n})_{n}$ is convergent and calculate its limit.

Let  $(w_{n})_{n}$ be the Arithmetic mean of $(v_{n})_{n}$.

- Show that 
  $\lim w_{n}=\lim v_{n}$ and deduce that  $u_n  \simeq \dfrac{n}{2}$.

[image]

it's not clear for me that  $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}^{*}: u_n \geq 1$
how we can prove it.

Since $\sqrt{n}$ is divergent to $+\infty$, $u_n$ is convergent to $+\infty$ by comparison.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems odd that $u_n$ is defined in terms of itself.  For b), do the traditional multiplication by the conjugate.

Answer (score 2):

It's clear that $u_k\ge1$ for all $k$ so we get *(I think there's a typo in the question)*

$$u_n=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\color{red}{n-1}}u_k\right)^{1/2}\ge \sqrt{n-1}$$
hence we get the desired limit of $u_n$, moreover we have

$$v_n(u_{n+1}+u_n)=u_n\iff \frac1{v_n}=1+\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}2$$
so we get the limit of $v_n$ and 
$$v_n=u_{n+1}-u_n=_\infty o(u_n)\iff u_{n+1}\sim_\infty u_n$$

Finally using Cesàro theorem and the telescoping sum we get
$$\frac{u_n}n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty} v_n=\frac12$$
hence we get the desired result.

Comment: $u_n$ is the square root of the sum of $n-1$ terms $u_k$. Every $u_k\ge1$ so we have $u_n\ge \sqrt{n-1}$. Of course this inequality is sufficient to get the limit of $u_n$ but it isn't a sharp inequality since in the last of the problem we get that $u_n\sim\frac{n}2$.

Comment: we can't show $u_n  \simeq  u_{n+1}$ before we show second question